# Select specific values as columns in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a Stored Procedure in MySQL to get a set of management information. The problem is: I need my results 'horizontally' instead of 'vertically'. To elaborate more, here's the database design I gotta deal with:

`users`

- company_id
- user_type_id

`companies`

- company_id

`user_types`

- user_type_id
- descriptor

So here's the deal:
I need to count all users grouped by descriptor, then grouped by company. I can to that like so:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS number,
    ut.descriptor,
    company_id
FROM
    users u

INNER JOIN
    user_types ut
ON ut.user_type_id = u.user_type_id
AND descriptor LIKE 'xyz%'

INNER JOIN
    companies c
ON u.company_id = c.company_id

GROUP BY
    ut.descriptor,
    company_id
```

This does give me the correct results, however: this list is 'vertical'. I get a new row for each descriptor. I actually want the descriptors to be the columns. Rows should be grouped by company. That's what the application logic expects.

I thought of fetching the descriptors first, doing the calculations later, but that leaves me with exactly the same issue. I could perform a subquery for each descriptor, but that would be very, very ugly.

As a summary, the expected result is something like this, where the 3 latter columns are actually descriptors from the user_types table:

`company` - `admin` - `customer` - `supplier`

`1 - 4 - 1 - 5`

`1 - 7 - 4 - 2`

This would translate into:
Company 1 has 4 admins, 1 customer, 5 suppliers.
Company 2 has 7 admins, 4 customers, 2 suppliers.

I really think I'm missing something here. What do I overlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this, but its not a dynamic width of the table.
and you may want to replace `IF(ut.descriptor = 'admin'`
with somthing like `IF(u.user_type_id = 1`
then you don't need to join in ut at all

```
SELECT
    company_id AS company,
    COUNT(IF(ut.descriptor = 'admin', 1, NULL) AS admin,
    COUNT(IF(ut.descriptor = 'customer', 1, NULL) AS customer,
    COUNT(IF(ut.descriptor = 'supplier', 1, NULL) AS supplier
FROM
    users u

INNER JOIN
    user_types ut
ON ut.user_type_id = u.user_type_id
AND descriptor LIKE 'xyz%'

INNER JOIN
    companies c
ON u.company_id = c.company_id

GROUP BY
    company_id
```

Comment: Hm... That does look legit. I'm gonna try this.